# C++: Parse a string without stringstream

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  std:: string menuChoice;
  int nArrayNumber = 0;
  int nAuthorArrayNumber = 0;
  int nElementArrayNumber = 0;
  pCurrentMediaItem = aMediaItemArray;
  
  displayMediaMenu();
  while (!finished)
    {
      std::cin.clear();
      interActive = isatty(fileno(stdin));
      std:: cout << std::endl << "Menu[" << nArrayNumber << "]:";
      getline (std::cin, menuChoice);
      charOption(menuChoice, 
                 pCurrentMediaItem, 
                 nArrayNumber,
                 finished,
                 nAuthorArrayNumber,
                 nElementArrayNumber);
```

C++ : How can I parse a string and assign the integers to other variables and a name to a separate string variable.

For example: an authors Birth Year, Death Year, and Name must be entered and that string must be sent to a switch statement which will parse the string and assign the separate members to other variables?

Comment: It's not too hard if you take away the "must be sent to a switch statement" requirement.  `switch{case}` won't help with this at all.

Comment: using good-ol' pointers (or iterators for std::string), in combination with `std::isalnum`, `std::isdigit` etc

Comment: @vsoftco: I don't see any ban on `strtol`, for example, which is great because it tells you where one number ends and you should start parsing the next field.

Comment: @BenVoigt good point, forgot about `strtol`

Comment: C++11 added std::stoi, std::stoul, std::stod and many others

Comment: Ben Voigt it must be a switch statement because it is essential a menu option being chosen so you choose the "c" option and sends that c to a switch case where you then must parse the string. My Professor has us use test scripts to help him grade so his test script is: c 1888 1999 Author Name

Comment: Hopefully that helps a little!

Comment: @JosephMehltretter: But you are not "sending the string to a switch statement".  Read and parse the string after you're in the right case.  Or is the command part of the same string?  Then you may have to begin parsing and pull out the command.  `switch` does not work on strings.  Some examples of input would help.

Comment: @BenVoigt the command is apart of the string and is sent to the switch statement. Here is examples of my code:

Comment: std:: string menuChoice;
  int nArrayNumber = 0;
  int nAuthorArrayNumber = 0;
  int nElementArrayNumber = 0;
  pCurrentMediaItem = aMediaItemArray;
  
  displayMediaMenu();
  while (!finished)
    {
      std::cin.clear();
      interActive = isatty(fileno(stdin));
      std:: cout << std::endl << "Menu[" << nArrayNumber << "]:";
      getline (std::cin, menuChoice);
      charOption(menuChoice,

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on trying to parse the string `c 1888 1999 Author Name` you may consider creating a switch statement with the first character. For example:

```
Author cAuthor;
switch(clever_name[0]) {
    case 'c':
        Author = find_author(clever_name);
        break;
    default:
        // do something else
}
```

with `Author` being a class with a name, year of birth and year of death and `find_author` being the horrendous spaghetti code below. I used the STL's string constructor extensively along with `find_first_of`, `find_first_not_of`, and `find_last_of` which return a position in the string.

```
Author find_author(std::string s) {
    std::string nums("0123456789");
    std::string chars(
         "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrxtuvwxyz"
                      );
    size_t pos = s.find_first_of(nums); // find the first number
    int birth = std::atoi(
        std::string(
            s, // string to copy from
            pos, // position of first integer
            // the next line finds out how many characters we need to copy
            std::string(s.begin() + pos, s.end()).find_first_not_of(nums)
        ).c_str()
        );

    // increment pos to the next character that is not a number
    pos += std::string(s.begin() + pos, s.end()).find_first_not_of(nums);

    // then increment again to the next character that is a number
    pos += std::string(s.begin() + pos, s.end()).find_first_of(nums);

    // do the same thing again to find the next date
    int death = std::atoi(
        std::string(
            s,
            pos,
            std::string(s.begin() + pos, s.end()).find_first_not_of(nums)
        ).c_str()
        );

    // increment pos to the position of the first alphabetic character
    pos += std::string(s.begin() + pos, s.end()).find_first_of(chars);

    // do the same thing we did to find the numbers to extract the name
    std::string name =
        std::string(
            s,
            pos,
            std::string(
                   s.begin() + pos, s.end()
                        ).find_last_not_of(nums) + 1
            );
    return(Author(name, birth, death));
}
```

Comment: No problem man! Glad it helped. If you're working with c++11 or later you also might want to look into using regex